# Obtain failure::Fail in actix-web 1.0 Middleware

Tags: error-handling, rust, actix-web

I'm using actix-web 1.0

I'm writing a Middleware that must capture Errors and their stacktrace. The problem is that I can only access `ServiceRequest`s, which contain an `actix_web::Error`.

From this I must obtain a `failure::Fail`, but I can't find any way to do so. Previously I could do `Error::as_fail()`, but this function isn't available anymore with version 1.0

How can I obtain an error that implements `Fail` in my Middleware?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a solution to this.

Instead, the situation has evolved to a point where `failure` is not needed anymore and I can just deal with std `Error`s.